# Why can't I see new features in my Eclipse update site?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ibm-rational

In a nutshell: *I've updated some features in my Eclipse update site, but the new versions  are not showing, only the existing (installed) ones are*.

### Background

I have written a number of plugins (transformation extensions) in RSA to enable model-driven development (turning a platform-independent UML model into Java).

In order to share these with fellow developers, I created an Eclipse update site. I have 1 feature per plugin (yes I realize this is overkill, but I was unable to install some plugins when they were grouped together in a feature). After building the update site, I checked the whole site into source control - other developers just checkout the site, add it as a local update site in RSA, and install all of the plugins.

I have since updated a number of plugins (incrementing their version), updated their owning features (incrementing the version), rebuilt the update site and checked it in. This has worked fine - other developers just checkout the updated site and install the new versions of the plugins.

### Problem

I have recently updated the plugins again, updated the features and rebuilt the update site, but **the new versions of the features do not appear in the update site** (e.g. via `Help->Software Updates->Available Software`)! It's as if it's cached the old update site somewhere, because it's still showing the versions I have installed. The versions of the features and plugins in the built site are all the correct (new) versions.

I have tried:

- Refreshing the update site
- Removing the update site and adding it back
- Uninstalling all of the plugins and the update site (when I add the site again, it still only shows the old versions)
- Deleting all files in the update site except .project and site.xml and rebuilding (after I noticed the artifacts.xml still mentioned the old versions), still no luck
- using RSA 8.0.4 (which already had the old versions installed as well)

Has anyone come across this before or knows why this is happening?

I'm using IBM Rational Software Architect 7.5.5.2 (based on Eclipse 3.4.2).

Comment: Are you using the old Eclipse update mechanism? It's possible that the RSA product is using the p2 mechanism for its update site stuff which is why it would not see your new stuff.

Comment: Yes I'm using the `site.xml` mechanism - which I believe is still supported and obviously works (it installed the plugins in the first place), but doesn't seem to pick up changes to the site (even though it's worked for me before)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I actually got it to work, but it's not exactly the most elegant solution - if anyone can think of an alternative solution (or reason why this is happening) I would appreciate it!

All I did was

- delete all files in my update site, except `.project` and `site.xml`
- remove all features from my site
- add the features back to the site
- build the site
- remove update site from the *Available Software* section in RSA (it complained that the site didn't exist before I did this)
- add the site again

Once I did this, the new versions appeared and I was able to update them successfully. I'm still not sure if the first step is necessary or not though...

Comment: Ahh, yes, you are using something based on Eclipse 3.4 and that was the first p2 release which was pretty flaky sometimes in detecting new versions due to bugs. Newer Eclipse releases are much better, and you might have better luck with the classic update mechanism in that release. I'm not sure you will be able to do any better than your workaround.

Comment: It's interesting it didn't work in RSA8 (based on Eclipse 3.6) either. Maybe it depends on the version you use to _build_ the site. We're moving to RSA8 soon anyway, so it may not be an issue next time.

Comment: Yes, that is odd, 3.6 is much better at finding things. And since you are building the old stuff I can't see why the version you are using to build it would make any difference.